# Laravel 5.2 Relationship hasMany with another unique identifier

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I am learning laravel and trying to set up a blocked user list, for example if you want to block a user from viewing your profile you would block them, I have done this however I am just wondering if the way I have done it is correct.

Below is what I have done. My main question is, Is there another way to set up a identifier with out creating a new db field called unique_id where I would put both user ids in and then query it each time.

**The Database Migration:**

```
  Schema::create('blocked_users', function(Blueprint $table)
  {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
      $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
      $table->integer('blocked_user_id')->unsigned();
      $table->foreign('blocked_user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
      $table->integer('unique_id')->unique();
      $table->text('reason')->nullable();
      $table->timestamps();
  });
```

**The user model**

```
public function BlockedUsers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User\BlockedUsers');
}
```

Then when I am blocking a user I enter the blocked users id and the current users id as the unique_id

and then this is the messy part which I am doing which I believe there should be an easier way.

```
if (BlockedUsers::whereUniqueId($user->id.Auth::user()->id)->exists()) {
    $blocked = 1;
 } else {
    $blocked = 0;
 }
```

I am trying to think of a way to set up a function in the user model to check if the user_id is = to the current user and the blocked_user_id is equal to the users profile id.

ALl i can think of is

```
public function isUserBlocked()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User\BlockedUsers', 'blocked_user_id');
}
```

But obviously this would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just take care of this inside of some middleware applied to the route.

```
php artisan make:middleware UserCanViewProfile
```

Then we assume that the middleware will be applied to routes that have a `Profile` model, such as this:

```
Route::get('/profile/{profile}', 'ProfileController@show');
```

Now we'll fetch the instance of the profile in our middleware by accessing it through the `route` and then we'll check if the user has a block that contains the `profile user id` and the `auth user id`.

```
$profile = $this->route('profile');
$$block = BlockedUsers::where('user_id', $profile->user->id)->where('blocked_user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();

if (empty($block)) {
    return $next($request);    
} else {
    abort(403, 'You are not allowed to view that profile!');
}
```

Of course you need to register this middleware in your `App\Http\Kernel` file under the `$routeMiddleware`, something like this:

```
'usercanviewprofile' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserCanViewProfile::class,
```

Then apply it to your `routes`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['usercanviewprofile'], 'prefix' => 'profile'], function(){
    Route::get('{profile}', 'ProfileController@show');
});
```

Or if you're using `CRUD` patterns:

```
Route::resource('profile', 'ProfileController')->middleware('usercanviewprofile');
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Im really sorry I have already set up the way to check if the user is blocked, I was just wondering if the way I have done it is correct.                I have done this however I am just wondering if the way I have done it is correct.

"Below is what I have done. My main question is, Is there another way to set up a identifier with out creating a new db field called unique_id where I would put both user ids in and then query it each time"

Comment: @Unifx Yes, the method I've outlined above does not require any of that.

Comment: Oh sorry I did not see that part, Thanks again